# Java Do While loop

Tags: java

I know that in a while loop the do loop gets iterate first then the condition is checked. But Why does this code print 3, shouldn't it go into an infinity loop? But if i replace b = !b with true. It does go into an infinite loop. why is that? (i am a newbie so i could be missing something dumb)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   boolean b = false;
   int i = 1;
    do{
        i++ ;
    } while (b = !b);           //shouldn't this loops forever, if i put true, it does loop for ever why?
    System.out.println( i );    //prints 3
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You are using the assignment operator `=`, not the comparison operator `==`.

In the first iteration, `i++` occurs and `i` is now `2`.  You assign `!b`, or `true`, to `b`, and that is the `while` loop condition.  The condition is satisfied, so the next iteration takes place.

In the second iteration, `i++` occurs and `i` is now `3`.  You assign `!b`, or `false`, to `b`, and that is the `while` loop condition.  The condition is not satisfied, so the `do`-`while` loop ends, and `3` is printed.

If you said `while (b == b);`, then that would be an infinite loop.  `while (b != b);` would break out after the first iteration, printing `2`.

Comment: while (b == !b) will break out of the loop. while (b != !b) will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @ddalton That's what happens when I don't test!  Fixed.

Comment: oh ok!!! So on the second iteration the !b changes back to false...... ok cool so thats what i missed, !(NOT)

Answer (score 1):

The first time b = !b is evaluated, b will be set to true and the resulting expression is true so the loop runs again.

On the second encounter the expression evaluates to false so the loop exits.

By then, i will have been incremented twice. So the final value is 3.